# obtaining the rest of a clause as a list and creating a list of lists

Tags: prolog

let's say that I have some clauses, two of which are the following:

```
has_basket('Sarah', 'bigBasket','apple','grape').
has_basket('Sarah', 'bigBasket','orange','berry').
```

How can I write a rule named

```
all_baskets(S,L).
```

which will give me the list of all the baskets that person S has in the following form?
for example

```
all_baskets('Sarah',L).
```

will give us:

```
L=[['bigBasket','apple','grape], ['bigBasket','orange','berry']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you consider a Prolog programming problem, you need to clarify the aspects that are important to you.

1. Think of the order of the two elements in the list. Are they in that order because they are in alphabetical ascending order, or is it just luck?
2. What do you expect for `all_baskets('Nemo', L)`? Should this fail, or rather answer `L = []`?
3. What do you expect for `all_baskets(P, [])`?

If you say 1 alphabetical, 2 fail, and 3 fail, then `setof/3` is the way to go.

```
has_basket('Sarah',  bigBasket, apple, grape).
has_basket('Sarah',  bigBasket, orange, berry).
has_basket('Bernie', bigBasket, orange, apple).  % another fact

all_baskets(P, L) :-
   setof([A, B, C], has_basket(P, A, B, C), L).

?- all_baskets(P, []).
   false.
?- all_baskets('Nemo', L).
   false.
?- all_baskets(P, L).
   P = 'Bernie', L = [[bigBasket,orange,apple]]
;  P = 'Sarah', L = [[bigBasket,apple,grape],[bigBasket,orange,berry]].
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the [**`findall/3`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3):

```
all_baskets(S,L) :-
    findall([A, B, C], has_basket(S, A, B, C), L).
```

Here `[A, B, C]` is the "template" of the items in the list, `has_basket(S, A, B, C)` the "goal" that needs be fullfilled, and `L` the list of results.